# Difference between Service and Manager classes in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, naming-conventions

I'm getting a little confused about the `Manager` and `Service` class name suffix.

As far as I understand the difference, `Managers` are responsible for handling (creating, retrieving, deleting, ...) certain types of entities. For instance, the `ModuleManager` is responsible for loading and returning `Modules`. In this case, you *do* care about the actual entity, the `Module`.

However, `Services` are classes that provide interfaces to execute cetain types of process logic. For example, a `LogService` sends a given log message to the defined log writer. You don't care where it goes and what it does, you just want the admin to be informed about what just happened.

Now, ZF2 provides a `ServiceManager` that creates and returns instances of a given `Service`. I accidentally got used to creating `Managers` and providing a `factory` to the `ServiceManager` so that you can access the `Manager` using `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('managerName');` in the `Controller` context in order to keep controllers tiny and the real logic in testable classes. This is the part that is confusing me right now because obviously, it can't be recommended to retrieve `Managers` using a `ServiceLocator`. **BUT**: I'm not the only one doing this: The `Doctrine ORM` module is another example for this: It registers the `EntityManager` as a `doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default` **`Service`** by default.

Am I getting the true difference between `Services` and `Managers` wrong? Is there even a difference? Are `Managers` maybe even inherited from `Services` in the concept?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'll try to break down managers and services in ZF2 for you.

### Managers

Unfortunately, the word 'manager' in reference to classes is incredibly ambiguous and within ZF2, there's a bit of inconsistency with how the word is used. Thus, there's truly no authoritative definition for what a 'manager' is in ZF2. Currently, the 'Managers' in ZF2 can best be broken down like this:

- **ServiceManager** — An instance of `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`. There can be multiple ServiceManager instances -- by default, there's just the "main" service manager, which is configured with the 'services' config key or by the array(s) returned by Module's getServiceConfig() method.
- **Plugin Managers** — These extend `Zend\ServiceManager\PluginManager` which extends `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` with some specialized functionality. These are spread throughout many components in the framework, and provide the functionality of what was previously known (in earlier versions of ZF2) as Plugin Loaders/Brokers. These plugin managers are what initialize things like [view helpers](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php), [controller plugins](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/PluginManager.php), and [controllers themselves](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/ControllerManager.php).
- **Other 'Managers'** — Things like `Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager` and `Zend\Session\SessionManager`. These have nothing to do with the ServiceManager, but just happen to have 'Manager' as a suffix to their name.

I think you may be getting confused trying to assign a definition to a term (Manager) that was not designed with any specific definition in mind. As the author of `Zend\ModuleManager`, I can tell you that I originally developed the component as `Zend\Module` (I really don't like Manager as a suffix). It was decided in [one of our weekly IRC meetings](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/2012-05-16+Meeting+Log) that `Zend\Module` is ambiguous and that suffixing it with 'Manager' would somehow resolve that ambiguity. Obviously I was out-voted on the matter. My point is, `Zend\ModuleManager` was not developed to any specification of being a 'manager', by any definition.

### Services

In ZF2, with regard to `Zend\ServiceManager`, 'services' are simply objects (and can technically also be arrays). The ServiceManager component can be thought of as a simple key-value registry for the various 'services' (objects) your application might need. These 'services' are typically things like a configured mailer, logger, database adapter, application config, etc. Of course the ServiceManager is not *just* a simple registry, and its primary function is to defer instantiation of the services (and their dependencies) until they're actually needed; aka lazy loading); I've written a [blog post which explains the various features of the ServiceManager in depth](http://blog.evan.pro/introduction-to-the-zend-framework-2-servicemanager).

> I accidentally got used to creating Managers and providing a factory to the ServiceManager so that you can access the Manager using $this->getServiceLocator()->get('managerName)

I think in this case you may be confusing the term 'manager' with 'service' here. Things registered with the ServiceManager can simply be referred to as 'services'. This could be confusing because you could, indeed, register some sort of 'manager' as a service. For instance, you could have a 'session' service that's an instance of `Zend\Session\SessionManager`. Further confusion ensues, as the term 'service' generally refers to a class which makes up part of a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

So, unfortunately, yes, the terminology in ZF2 can be a bit foggy, but once you understand a couple of relatively simple core concepts, the great design really opens up some amazing flexibility that is, in my opinion, unparalleled by most of the other existing frameworks out there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Evan, thank you for this great answer, it helps a lot! Now, I have to consider how to name "Managers" in future and what to do with my existing ones, but that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: This is really very clarifying and I suggest including it in the introduction of the ZF2 documentation under a paragraph called 'ZF2 Terminology' or similar.

Comment: You (or anyone else) has my full permission to include / paraphrase this into the ZF2 documentation. Anyone is free to contribute to the docs at https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation. I'm just not sure when/if I'll have to time to get around to it otherwise. :)